# How to move image file on AWS S3 using Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, amazon-s3

I want to move a file from a folder to another folder on s3 but it is not moving to destination folder correctly. My code is below:

```
     $old_path = "media_manager/omm/pic.jpg"
     $new_path = "media_manager/omm/mypics/pic.jpg"

     Storage::disk('s3')->move($old_path, $new_path)
```

It returns true and image file disappeared in old(source) folder but it is not showing up in destination(new) folder.  I dont know why?  I am using ajax to do this. 
Plz help in this regard.  Thanks

Comment: This method as per your example has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

is the mypics folder exists on AWS S3 Bucket?

if no try to add the folder "mypics" manually and make sure that you have the permission to write he file inside of it

Comment: Yes that folder exists

Comment: mmm..what you can do is to change the disk to local and to try this with Storage::disk('local')..if this works locally on your machine then for sure you dont have a write permission on this folder on AWS S3, you have to check for the permission of the Folder